# Class to display flash screen

Tags: android, android-layout

I would like to create a "Flash" class to display a white flash screen (200ms) as easily as a toast, like this:

```
Flash.create(context).show();
```

- This layer should appear instantly then gradually disappear (alpha transition)
- It must not catch events
- It must adapt to the screen rotation
- It can be created from any activity

I looked for a solution via WindowManager but I am having some difficulties.
What solution do you recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for many hours, it seems impossible to delegate events from one window to another. So the final functional solution I've found is to extend an activity so that it achieves this flash effect. For those who are interested in it, here's my subclass:

```
public class FlmActivity extends Activity {


    private final static int DURATION_FADEIN = 50;
    private final static int DURATION_FADEOUT = 200;
    private final static int DURATION_INTERVAL = 200;
    private View view;
    private AnimationSet anim;
    private int count;


    public FlmActivity() {
        super();
    }


    @Override protected void onPostCreate(Bundle state) {
        super.onPostCreate(state);
        view = new View(this) {{
            setBackgroundColor(0xffffffff);
            setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }};
        anim = new AnimationSet(false) {{
            addAnimation(new AlphaAnimation(0, 1) {{
                setDuration(DURATION_FADEIN);
            }});
            addAnimation(new AlphaAnimation(1, 0) {{
                setStartOffset(DURATION_FADEIN);
                setDuration(DURATION_FADEOUT);
            }});
            addAnimation(new Animation() {{
                setStartOffset(DURATION_FADEIN + DURATION_FADEOUT);
                setDuration(DURATION_INTERVAL);
                setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
                    @Override public void onAnimationStart(Animation anim) {}
                    @Override public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation anim) {}
                    @Override public void onAnimationEnd(Animation anim) {
                        flash(count - 1);
                    }
                });
            }});
        }};
        addContentView(view, getWindow().getAttributes());
    }


    @Override protected void onDestroy() {
        ((ViewGroup) view.getParent()).removeView(view);
        super.onDestroy();
    }


    public final void flash(int count) {
        if((this.count = count) > 0) {
            view.startAnimation(anim);
        }
    }


}
```

Code to call flash effect in an extended activity:

```
flash(10);
```

With this implementation, the events pass through the layer

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues with that, as you'll have to pass the Activity and not just a Context into the "Flash" screen. Therefore the handling of screen rotation will be tricky.

I've created and open-sourced a [small library called Crouton](https://github.com/neofoniemobile/Crouton) that can help you.
Currently it still struggles with the issue of orientation changes while a Crouton is being displayed.

Comment: This is not exactly what I want to do, but your work is interesting! Thank you for your quick answer

Comment: I know it is not very "user-friendly" but I want to display this flash in a persistent mode exactly like a toast

Comment: Do you know that you can [set the View of a Toast](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#setView(android.view.View))?

Comment: good idea, I'll try a custom white toast with an animated view (fade-out to 200ms, I don't know if it's possible), thank you for this reply, I'll inform you

Answer (score 0):

So I give my own solution if it can help anybody...
(I changed the call to flash method since my first post)

```
public class Flasher {


    private final static int DURATION_OFFSET = 300;
    private final static int DURATION_FADEIN = 50;
    private final static int DURATION_FADEOUT = 200;
    private Animation fadein;
    private Animation fadeout;
    private RelativeLayout flash;
    private RelativeLayout view;
    private Toast toast;
    private int count;


    public Flasher(Context context) {
        fadein = new AlphaAnimation(0, 1);
        fadein.setStartOffset(DURATION_OFFSET);
        fadein.setDuration(DURATION_FADEIN);
        fadein.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
            @Override public void onAnimationStart(Animation anim) {}
            @Override public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation anim) {}
            @Override public void onAnimationEnd(Animation anim) {
                flash.startAnimation(fadeout);
            }
        });
        fadeout = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
        fadeout.setDuration(DURATION_FADEOUT);
        fadeout.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
            @Override public void onAnimationStart(Animation anim) {}
            @Override public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation anim) {}
            @Override public void onAnimationEnd(Animation anim) {
                if(count > 1) {
                    flash(count - 1);
                } else {
                    cancel();
                }
            }
        });
        LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(-1, -1);
        flash = new RelativeLayout(context);
        flash.setLayoutParams(params);
        flash.setBackgroundColor(0xffffffff);
        flash.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        view = new RelativeLayout(context);
        view.setLayoutParams(params);
        view.addView(flash);
        toast = new Toast(context);
        toast.setView(view);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.FILL, 0, 0);
    }


    public final void flash(int count) {
        toast.show();
        this.count = count;
        flash.startAnimation(fadein);
    }


    public final void cancel() {
        toast.cancel();
    }


}
```

---

MainActivity for test it:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    private static Flasher flasher;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
        super.onCreate(state);
        View layout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
        setContentView(layout);
        if(flasher == null) {
            flasher = new Flasher(this);
        }
        layout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override public void onClick(View v) {
                flasher.flash(1);
            }
        });
    }


    @Override protected void onDestroy() {
        if(isFinishing()) {
            flasher = null;
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }


}
```

Thank you to Keyboardsurfer for the help!

---

Edit: a constraint is not satisfied:
The Toast does not dispatch the touch event:

```
flasher.flash(10);
```

MainActivity is not touchable during flashes effect
If anybody have a solution to resolve the problem...